# How can i improve performance of Flutter DataTable Widget?

Tags: performance, flutter, datatable

```
DataTable(
          columnSpacing: 1,
          headingRowHeight: 35,
          dataRowHeight: 36,
          columns: [
            DataColumn(
              label: Expanded(
                child: Container(
                    color: Color(int.parse(widget.classObj.color)),
                    padding: Utils.tableHeaderPadding(),
                    child: Utils.tableHeaderText('No')),
              ),
            ),
            DataColumn(
              label: Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                color: Color(int.parse(widget.classObj.color)),
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50, vertical: 5),
                child: Utils.tableHeaderText('Name'),
              )),
            ),
            if (studentAttendance.isNotEmpty)
              for (var item in studentAttendance)
                DataColumn(
                  label: InkWell(
                    onTap: () => _createDateDeleteDialogue(
                        context, _user.emailUid, widget.classObj.classId, item),
                    child: Container(
                        color: Color(int.parse(widget.classObj.color)),
                        padding: Utils.tableHeaderPadding(),
                        child: Utils.tableHeaderText(item)),
                  ),
                ),
            if (studentAttendance.isNotEmpty) ...[
              DataColumn(
                label: Container(
                    color: Color(int.parse(widget.classObj.color)),
                    padding: Utils.tableHeaderPadding(),
                    child: Utils.tableHeaderText('Total Present')),
              ),
              DataColumn(
                label: Container(
                    color: Color(int.parse(widget.classObj.color)),
                    padding: Utils.tableHeaderPadding(),
                    child: Utils.tableHeaderText('Total Absent')),
              ),
              DataColumn(
                label: Container(
                    color: Color(int.parse(widget.classObj.color)),
                    padding: Utils.tableHeaderPadding(),
                    child: Utils.tableHeaderText('Total Attendance(%)')),
              ),
            ]
          ],
          rows: students.map((student) {
            int presence = student.attendanceList != null
                ? student.attendanceList.length
                : 0;
            int absent = studentAttendance.length - presence;
            double percent = (presence * 100) / studentAttendance.length;
            final attendanceWidget = AttendanceWidgetList(
              student: student,
              attendance: studentAttendance,
              isPresence: presence == 0 ? false : true,
              context: context,
              classId: widget.classObj.classId,
              email: _user.emailUid,
            );
            return DataRow(
              cells: [
                DataCell(
                  Center(
                    child: Text(
                      student.id.toString(),
                      style: Utils.tableSimpleText(),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                DataCell(
                  Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 5),
                    child: Text(
                      student.name,
                      style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 17, color: Colors.black),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                if (student.attendanceList != null &&
                    studentAttendance.isNotEmpty)
                  if (presence == 0)
                    ...attendanceWidget.attendanceListWidget().map((e) => e)
                  else if (absent == 0)
                    ...attendanceWidget.attendanceListWidget().map((e) => e)
                  else
                    ...studentAttendance.map((e) {
                      if (student.attendanceList.contains(e)) {
                        return AttendanceWidgetList(
                          student: student,
                          attendance: studentAttendance,
                          isPresence: true,
                          date: e,
                          context: context,
                          classId: widget.classObj.classId,
                          email: _user.emailUid,
                        ).attendanceSetter();
                      } else {
                        return AttendanceWidgetList(
                          student: student,
                          attendance: studentAttendance,
                          isPresence: false,
                          date: e,
                          context: context,
                          classId: widget.classObj.classId,
                          email: _user.emailUid,
                        ).attendanceSetter();
                      }
                    })
                else
                  ...attendanceWidget.attendanceListWidget().map((e) => e),
                if (studentAttendance.isNotEmpty) ...[
                  DataCell(
                    Center(
                      child: Text(
                        presence.toString(),
                        style: Utils.tableSimpleText(),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  DataCell(
                    Center(
                      child: Text(absent.toString(),
                          style: Utils.tableSimpleText()),
                    ),
                  ),
                  DataCell(
                    Center(
                      child: Text("${percent.toStringAsFixed(2)} %",
                          style: Utils.tableSimpleText()),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ],
            );
          }).toList(),
        ),
```

I have tried all possible solutions like adding some less widget in datatable.
But DataTable performance isn't increasing.

So, any who have idea how can i increase performance of DataTable
Reference DataTable Video Link : https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1vpdt0uBK5JV88wHabw6zd-dK76EFF_nR?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `PaginatedDataTable()` instead of `DataTable()` widget.

A paginated data table shows rows of data per page and provides controls for showing other pages.

[PaginatedDataTable Refrence Link](http://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/PaginatedDataTable-class.html#:%7E:text=A%20paginated%20data%20table%20shows,is%20presented%20as%20a%20Card.)

[Reference video link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UQ_0J_1wzZ4)